# Kubernetes ServiceAccount have roles and rolesbinding permissions can't create roles

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a service account that has the permissions to create roles and rolebindings, but sadly it gets an error when it tries to create a role. It seems like IAM permissions takes precedence? How can that be?

I get this error:

```
You either need to be cluster-admin or create a service-account that have the permission "Required "container.roles.create" permission."
```

#### Is this a bug that a Kubernetes Serviceaccount is prevented from creating roles (not clusterroles) in namespaces?

I could probably solve it by giving the serviceaccount cluster-admin, but that is too extensive as the serviceaccount should not have access to everything.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: rbac-sync
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: role-creator
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["rbac.authorization.k8s.io"]
    resources: ["roles", "rolebindings"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: rbac-sync-role-creator
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: role-creator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: rbac-sync
  namespace: default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the GCP documentation, [setting up Role-Based access control](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control#setting_up_role-based_access_control):

> Because of the way GKE checks permissions when you create a Role or ClusterRole, you must first create a RoleBinding that grants you all of the permissions included in the role you want to create.
>   An example workaround is to create a RoleBinding that gives your Google identity a **cluster-admin role** before attempting to create additional Role or ClusterRole permissions.

Comment: Thanks for that, I overlooked it! Either overlooked the blue parts or didn't think that it related to serviceaccounts.

Comment: No problem, I’m glad to help.